TRP radiation pattern from 2D slices
I need your help to solve this issue.
I have 2D radiation patterns of power measurements on the XY, YZ and XZ planes.
The output is a .csv file; in the first colunm we have the rotation angle from 0 to 360° by 5° steps (73x 1).
Second column is the power measurement from the antenna DUT rotation on the XY plane, 4th column is power on the YZ plane and finally the 6th column is power on the XZ plane.
I want to interpolate the values to get the 3D radiation pattern on the sphere.
I am stack at a mismatch issue at this line X = R . sin(Phi) .* cos(Theta); Operator .: Wrong dimensions for operation [1x2] . [100x100], same dimensions expected.
I am using scilab and here is my code
// Extract angles and power values
angles_XY = data(:, 1); // First column: angles which are varying from 0 to 360 by 5° steps
power_XY = data(:, 2);  // Second column: power when the DUT is rotated on the XY plane at each 5° step

angles_YZ = data(:, 1);
power_YZ = data(:, 4);

angles_XZ = data(:, 1);
power_XZ = data(:, 6);

// Step 2: Interpolate the data
angles_interp = linspace(0, 360, 100); // Interpolated angles from 0 to 360 degrees

power_XY_interp = interp1(angles_XY, power_XY, angles_interp, 'linear');
power_YZ_interp = interp1(angles_YZ, power_YZ, angles_interp, 'linear');
power_XZ_interp = interp1(angles_XZ, power_XZ, angles_interp, 'linear');

// Step 3: Convert to spherical coordinates
theta = angles_interp * %pi / 180; // Convert interpolated angles to radians (0 to 360 degrees)
phi = linspace(0, 180, 100) * %pi / 180; // Polar angle from 0 to 180 degrees

// Create the grid
[Theta, Phi] = meshgrid(theta, phi);
R = ones(size(Theta)); // Radius is 1 for a unit sphere

// Step 4: Map power values onto the sphere
Power_3D = zeros(size(Theta));
for i = 1:length(phi)
    for j = 1:length(theta)
        Power_3D(i, j) = power_XY_interp(j) + power_YZ_interp(i) + power_XZ_interp(j); // Simplified combination
    end
end

// Convert spherical coordinates to Cartesian for plotting
X = R .* sin(Phi) .* cos(Theta);
Y = R .* sin(Phi) .* sin(Theta);
Z = R .* cos(Phi);

// Step 5: Plot the spherical radiation pattern
clf();
surf(X, Y, Z, Power_3D);
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Power (dB)');
title('3D Spherical Radiation Pattern');
colorbar;

Can someone help ?
Thanks
